# Return from await() from other method

Tags: java, playframework, web-frameworks

I’m newbie in Play! and I have one question about asynchronous programming in HTTP.
I have a piece of code like this:

```
public void someMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        doSomething();
        await(someTime);
    }
}
```

This method is invoked by user by sending GET/POST request.
It does some computations (*doSomething()*) and after that it waits some time.
But: the user has to have ability to “return” from *await(someTime)* and the loop should continue next iteration without waiting all the *“someTime”* time.

The example code:

```
public void nextAwait() {
    continueАForLoop();
}
```

The user invokes nextAwait() method by GET/POST.
If it is invoked, the loop will continue and *doSomething()* will be (has to be) invoked immediately!

So, is it possible in Play?

Thanks in advance for answers :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to this, is to wait for a shorter period of time, then check some value for user interaction, and then continue waiting.

for example, let's assume your total wait time is 10 seconds

```
public void someMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        doSomething();
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            if (!userInterrupt) await("1s");
        }
    }
}
```

So, this breaks your wait down to 1 second chunks, and checks a value to see if the user has interrupted the wait. It means that the user will wait a maximum of 1 second before the processing is released.

Comment: OK, I know that I could use it that way, but e.g. 1 second is too long time for me to wait. Of course I can set 200ms,300 ms, but if `someTime` (this is value set by user) is quite big (e.g. - 1 min), and there're many users invoking this method concurrently, won't it reduce performance too much? I mean - the second loop will iterate quite fast for a long time.

Comment: yes, it most likely will degrade performance, but I am not sure you have much a choice with Play1.x. However, this is still better than most other frameworks, as it atleast frees the thread inbetween each check, whereas other frameworks would hold on to the thread for the full duration of the wait.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works this way but you could try something like that: (You have a field monitor = new Object() somewhere)

```
synchronized ( this.monitor ) {
  this.monitor.wait( someTime );
}
```

and in the other method you call:

```
synchronized ( monitor ) {
  this.monitor.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: this will wait the thread, but Play uses continuations, which actually puts the thread to one side, so that other http requests can be processed. So this will cause the http request thread to be blocked!